# Git find the oldest common ancestor of two branches

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I tried git merge-base, but it only provides the most recent common ancestor of two branches rather than the oldest one. Could anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: You mean the oldest root that both tips trace back to, or the oldest commit with multiple children whose descendants include both tips, or what?

Comment: Basically the oldest root. For example, I created a branch against the master branch called “Sky.” Because someone updated my master branch, so I later on made some pull requests from the master branch, and I am looking for the commit that creates “Sky” at the beginning.

Comment: Okay. That's not a root commit in Git lingo, root commits have no ancestors at all, they're the oldest commits in the entire history.  What you're asking for is a common request for people who want something Git already handles. You can get what you're after, `git rev-list --first-parent` on each tip and find the first common one, but nobody getting full value out of Git ever finds it useful.  Can you explain what you're going to use this for, what situation you're in that prompted this request?

Comment: Hi, jthill, thanks for helping. I am basically trying to count the lines of available code changes of a branch from final to initial. For example, after branch “Sky” is created, person A modified the code to add a line “a+b=c,” “c+d=e,” and made a commit for it. After that, person B merged the master branch into “Sky” to update the branch and remove “a+b=c”. Later after the code modification on branch “Sky” is approved, we decided to merge it into master with line_of_code_changes = 1 (because “a+b=c“ is removed by person B, “a+b=c” is not an available code change). Want line_of_code_changes.

Comment: You say you want to count available changes, and correctly show how Git doesn't count the reverted a=b+c change as available, but then say you want to count line_of_code_changes, meaning, what?  If a change is made and reverted ten times do you want to count it ten times?  If it's reverted without a merge do you want to count both the original change and its reversion as separate changes?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I was trying to describe is the following: person A added a line of code and push it, but person B thinks that line of code is incorrect, so person B remove that line of code. Unfortunately, under this situation, git will output added = 1 and removed = 1 rather than added = 0 and removed = 0 because that line of code is redundant. Hope my explanation makes more sense this time...

Comment: I'm sorry, no, the only thing I'm sure of is that what you're talking about now has no point of contact with what's in your original question, and it's getting to where I couldn't even identify the goalposts, let alone guess where they are now. I'm voting to close this as unclear. Please look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `git merge-base --all`.
2. Run `git rev-list --max-parents 0` on the result(s); these are the potential answers.
3. Define "oldest" for your purposes and select one of the commits shown in step 2. (Depending on your definition, adding `--topo-order` and choosing the last one output might suffice.)

Comment: Hi, torek, Can you please provide an example to show me how this works? Thanks!

Comment: The reason this works is that *every* ancestor of a common ancestor *is* a common ancestor (by definition).  So once `git merge-base` finds a [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor)—or with `--all`, finds all of them, as there may be more than one—every commit reachable from here back to each root commit is also a common ancestor. The root ones are almost certainly what you mean by "oldest". Follow the wikipedia link here for more information.

Comment: See [jthill's comment questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894178/git-find-the-oldest-common-ancestor-of-two-branches/63895625?noredirect=1#comment113013443_63894178) as well, since finding a root ancestor doesn't really seem very useful.

Comment: `git merge-base -all` does not produce multiple commits for branches that have merged into each other, e.g. master was merged into the feature branch multiple times.